# Understanding matches! macro

Tags: rust, macros

I'm trying to understand how the `matches!` macro is written.

```
macro_rules! matches {
    ($expression:expr, $(|)? $( $pattern:pat_param )|+ $( if $guard: expr )? $(,)?) => {
        match $expression {
            $( $pattern )|+ $( if $guard )? => true,
            _ => false
        }
    };
}
```

Two metavariables are not clear to me;

1. `$(|)?`
2. `$(,)?`

I understand the functionality of `?`:

> indicates an optional fragment with zero or one occurrences.

But I'm not understanding where these metavariables are used for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are not used *for* anything, they are syntactic allowances.

`$(|)?` makes it so you can start the pattern with a leading `|`, for uniformity with e.g. `match` patterns which also allow that:

```
matches!(a, |1|2);
```

If you create a copy of the macro and remove that group, you'll see that that syntax does not work anymore.

This is because while the leading `|` is part of [the `Pattern` production](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html) [`pat_param` matches the *PatternNoTopAlt* production](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables), and so does not include or allow for a leading `|`.

Similarly, the trailing `$(,)?` allows for a trailing comma on the pattern: rust supports trailing commas in function calls, so most expression-like and function-like macros will also support it as they make for convenient uniformity:

```
matches!(
    a,
    1|2,
);
```

Here again, if you create a copy of the macro and remove that group, trailing commas will fail to parse.

Comment: What is the difference between `matches!(a, |1|2);` & `matches!(a, 1|2);`?

Comment: Syntactically, one of them has a leading `|` on the pattern and the other not. Semantically? No difference whatsoever, they're the exact same. The leading `|` is similar to the trailing `,`, it allows for more uniform code when you have large patterns and need to break them up over multiple lines, starting every line with `|` makes the code easier to read (thanks to the uniformity, the differences jump out more), and it makes for better diff if/when new alternatives need to be added.